# Possible "binomial" formula for the Jones polynomial

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, jones-polynomial

The following conjectural "binomial" formula for the Jones polynomials

$$J(q)=(-1)^{n_-}q^{n_+-2n_-}\left(\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}(-q)^k (q+1/q)^{\ell_{k+1}-1}\right)$$

is for a knot or link with $N$ crossings with a vector $\ell=[N,N-1,N-2,.....,2,1,2]$.

It is possible to write the following closed form

$$J(q) = (-1)^{n_-}q^{n_+-2n_-}{\frac {{q}^{-N+1}+ \left( -1 \right) ^{N}{q}^{N+1}+ \left( -1 \right) ^{N}{q}
^{N+3}+ \left( -1 \right) ^{N}{q}^{N-1}
}{{q}^{2}+1}}$$

Such formula works well for the following knots : $3_1$, $5_1$, $7_1$, $9_1$, $K11a367$, $K13a4878$,...; and for the following links :  $L2a1$, $L4a1$, $L6a3$, $L8a14$,...

My questions are:

1. What is the knot that follows after $K13a4878$ in the  mentioned sequence? It must be a knot with $15$ crossings.
2. What is the link that follows after $L8a14$ in the  mentioned sequence? It must be a link with $10$ crossings.
3. Do you think that the "binomial" formula is correct?

Comment: I still don't see how to interpolate $[N,N-1,\dots 1,2]$. Do you mean $[N,N-1,\dots,2,1]$?

Comment: For example, in the case of trefoil knot, the vector is [3,2,1,2]

Comment: But is the implicit interpolation of the form $[N,N-1,\dots, 2,1,2]$?

Comment: Yes.  Other example, in the case of a knot with 7 crossings, the vector is [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2]

Comment: Regardless of the notation, the links in question are the (2,n) torus links (or possibly their mirror images).  The knots come from the odd values n=3,5,7,9,... and the links are the even values n=2,4,6,8,....  So the answers to questions 1 and 2 are T(2,15) and T(2,10).

Comment: Nice formulas are known for quantum knot polynomials for all torus links, see [Rosso-Jones](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216593000064)

Comment: The answer to question 2 is $L10a118$  ( http://katlas.org/wiki/L10a118 )